# C array manipulation protocol conversion

Tags: c, protocols, protocol-buffers

I'm attempting to perform a protocol conversion

first protocol

```
| 1 byte (address) | 1 byte (function code) |  0-254 bytes (data) | 2 bytes ( CRC )|
```

second protocol

```
| 2 bytes (address) | 2 bytes (0) | 2 bytes (length) | 1 byte (0) | 1 byte (function code) | 0-254 bytes (data) |
```

first protocol frame is received and its data should be remapped into second protocol frame

byte 0 of first protocol should be mapped to byte 0 and 1 of the second.

```
static int convert(uint8_t *buffer, int len, uint8_t* frame){

    frame[0] = 0x00;
    frame[1] = buffer[0];

    frame[2] = 0x00;
    frame[3] = 0x00;

    frame[4] = 0x00;
    frame[5] = len - 4 + 1;

    frame[6] = 0x00;

    frame[7] = buffer[1];

    memcpy(&frame[8], &buffer[2], len-4);

    return frame[5] + 6;
}


uint8_t buffIN[260]; // first protocol

uint8_t buffOUT[264]; // second protocol


/*READ DATA INT buffIN*/ 
//8 bytes received
// if frame is valid continue else signal error

int res = convert(&buffIN, 8  &buffOUT);
```

If someone use a different approach please let me know

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  There isn't enough information in the question to be able to give you an answer.  For example, what do the two 1-byte values in the first protocol mean?  Is one the length of the data? How long can the data be?  Is the CRC a 2-byte or a 4-byte value? In the second protocol, what are the various pairs of bytes supposed to contain? Are the 2-byte values big-endian or little-endian?  Does the CRC go in one of the 2-byte values?

Comment: There's a little more information, yes, but there's nowhere near enough information.  You said that byte 0 of the first protocol goes into bytes 2 and 3 of the second; presumably, one of those two bytes is a 0, but which one is zero?  Byte 1 of the first protocol is probably the length of the data; which of bytes in the second protocol is the length?  What do the other bytes in the second protocol hold?  Is the CRC part of that data?

Comment: maybe now is more clear

Comment: basically my proble is on one side i have a uint8 and on the other side the same value should be written as a  uint16

Comment: I could set first byte to 0 and copy the value to the second byte but i was wondering if there is a better solution

Comment: Considerably clearer — thank you.  There are two items that I can see needing clarification.  (1) How do you know how long the data is in the first protocol?  AFAICS, you'd have to pass the length to the conversion function since the protocol doesn't explicitly store a length.  (2) When you need to convert a single-byte address to a double-byte address, do you add zeros for the more significant byte, or for the less significant byte?  This harks back to my question about endian-ness (big-endian vs little-endian).  You have to know whether 0x34 in Protocol 1 maps to [0x00 0x34] or [0x34 0x00].

Comment: Similarly with the length; one of the two bytes will always be zero, but which one?  I think your function will need to become: `int convert_P1_P2(int p1_len, const uint8 *p1_data, uint8 *p2_data)` and the return value from the function will be the number of bytes used in the output (protocol 2) data buffer.  Also, `buffIn` at length 8 can only hold messages with up to 4 bytes of data, not 254 bytes.

Comment: Dang it .. I had an answer in the works :) As some advice, declare two `structs` - one for the header of each protocol - instead of working with raw unsigned char buffers. You will need to deal with endianness to determine which byte of the 16-bit conversions becomes zero. and be sure to use unsigned variables to avoid any sign extension. This is a generic problem and, if reworded properly, would allow for an answer which covers a lot of fundamental areas.

Comment: @kdopen: the 2-byte CRC at the end of a variable length block of data does not lend itself to a structure.

Comment: That's why I said "for the header of each protocol" (i.e. the fixed part. A "unsigned char data[1];" element at the end of the struct gives you a handle to where the data portion lies (via `offsetof(<struct>, data)`. As there is no length in the original protocol, then it is almost certainly fixed wrt to function. Which means *each message type* can have it's own struct (or a union) with the correct size fo the data field.

Comment: One other possibility, Michele, is that the operation code in protocol 1 determines the length of the data.  In that case, you'd need some data structure — probably just an array — which maps the operation code to the data length for the operation code.

Comment: @kdopen: C99 has flexible-array members so you don't need to use the 'struct hack' you're proposing.  This could be a good question, if only all the issues I've raised were addressed.  And yours sounds like it could be the basis for an answer. In this case, you don't need to use pack pragmas to get the structures to work, fortunately.  You do, somewhere along the line, have to deal with endian-ness if the intent is to send the structure down the wire without any further translation.

Comment: yeah, this was my bread and butter for many years (usually using C89 compilers). But VLA's can be problematic in a struct if they aren't the last element. Usually yo only want the CRC at a specific point in the process, so you just pick it out in one-off code and verify it then discard. I'd actually make the protocol 2 struct have a maximal length data array as it includes the data length.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler The protocol is MODBUS RTU and unfortunately it does not provide a field for length; protocol is little-endian. 8 is youst a referece is the number of bytes this devicde is sending me over the serial line

Comment: @kdopen: the flexible array member (which is closely related to, but distinct from, a VLA) is only allowed as the last element of the structure.  The 2-byte CRC is still marginally problematic; it would have to be encoded as two extra bytes at the end of the the FAM.

Comment: Then the redesigned interface is necessary; you have to tell the converter function how many bytes were in the incoming packet (and that number had better be at least 4 bytes).  The data portion of the packet is then `length - 4`.  So, you need to use (something similar to) the revised function interface.  If the protocol is little-endian, then `assert(length >= 4 && length < 260); OUT[0] = IN[0]; OUT[1] = OUT[2] = OUT[3] = 0; OUT[4] = length - 4; OUT[5] = 0; OUT[6] = 0; OUT[7] = IN[1]; memmove(&OUT[8], &IN[2], length - 4);` (using your parameter names and assuming the length is `length`).

Comment: That's ugly, but functional.  Were I designing it, I'd probably have functions to parse the incoming data and pack the outgoing data.  There'd probably be other packet formats to deal with, too, with different layouts.  At some point, you should use the CRC to validate the incoming packet; that's outside the remit of the question, though.

Comment: thanks all for the valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two aspects to doing protocol conversions which you need to consider: the differing characteristics of the transports, and differences in the data. The most important transport characteristic is the endianness of data, especially with regard to that of the processor on which your converter is running. Other characteristics might involve character set (pure ASCII vs some flavor of Unicode - or in the old days EBCDIC), the size of numeric values, date-formats etc. Differences in the data includes field order, field presence, and data representation (mapping one set of values onto another).

Also, most protocol converters need to go both ways.

Now go back and remember the most fundamental paradigm for a program: Input-Process-Output. This structure is extremely useful in protocol conversion. You want all processing (regardless of direction) to operate on sanitized data in a standard format. Therefore, define an internal representation for a protocol packet which is independent of either of the protocols to be converted. Design it to make the optimum use of the converter's processor.

Then write four routines:

- Convert protocol 1 to internal format
- Convert internal format to protocol 1
- Convert protocol 2 to internal format
- Convert internal format to protocol 2

And your simplified mainline becomes:

```
while(TRUE)
    if (protocol 1 packet available)
        convert it to internal format
        perform any necessary processing
        convert to protocol 2 and transmit
    endif
    if (protocol 2 packet available)
        convert it to internal format
        perform any necessary processing
        convert to protocol 1 and transmit
    endif
endwhile
```

This completely divorces the two protocol conversion from knowing about each other, and makes it very easy to switch out one or another for an alternative, or respond to changes in one of them.

Now to your specific example, my internal structure would look something like:

```
typedef struct internalForm {
    unsigned int address;
    unsigned int function;
    size_t payloadLength;
    unsigned char payload[255];
} internalForm;
```

and my four methods would have these prototypes:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
bool   P1ToInternal(const unsigned char *packet, size_t packetLength, internalForm * internal);
size_t InternalToP1(const internalForm * internal, unsigned char *packet, size_t packetLength);
bool   P2ToInternal(const unsigned char *packet, size_t packetLength, internalForm * internal);
size_t InternalToP2(const internalForm * internal, unsigned char *packet, size_t packetLength);
```

The `bool` return is simply to indicate conversion failures for inputs. The 'output' functions return the size of the converted packet - or 0 on error.

In more complex conversions, I would actually have an internal representation for things like the function code and other "enumerated" fields. The conversion routines would take care of the mapping between internal representations and protocol-specific ones.

Complete implementation of one direction might be:

```
bool P1ToInternal(const unsigned char *packet, size_t packetLength, internalForm * internal)
{
    internal->address = (unsigned int) packet[0];
    internal->function = (unsigned int) packet[1];

    // You need to write the function below. It could just be a look up
    size_t dataLength = MapP1FunctionToPayloadLength(internal->function);
    if (dataLength > sizeof(internal->payload))
        return false;

    // You need to write CheckCRC()
    if (!CheckCRC(&packet[2], dataLength, &packet[2+dataLength]))
        return false;

    internal->payloadLength = dataLength;
    memset(internal->payload, 0, sizeof(internal->payload));
    memcpy(internal->payload, &packet[2], dataLength);
    return true;
}

size_t InternalToP2(const internalForm * internal, unsigned char *packet, size_t bufferLength)
{
    if (bufferLength < internal->payloadLength + 8)
        return 0;

    memset(packet, 0, bufferLength);

    // Assumes little-endian representation, but it's not hard to see what 
    // to do for the alternative. And you should have an enum for the array
    // indices.
    packet[1] = internal->address & 0xff;
    packet[5] = internal->payloadLength; // Not sure where your +1 is coming from
    packet[7] = internal->function & 0xff;
    memcpy(&payload[8], internal->payload, internal->payloadLength);

    return internal->PayloadLength + 8;
}
```

This may seem like overkill for your simple example, but as a framework it will lead to very robust conversion programs. Conversion errors will be very obvious and easy to debug. Input and output conversion, and internal processing can all be unit-tested independently.

Finally, a conversion would look like:

```
unsigned char inBuff[260], outBuff[264];

struct internalForm internal;

if (P1ToInternal(inBuff, sizeof(inBuff), &internal))
{
    size_t len = InternalToP2(&internal, outBuff, sizeof(outBuff))
    if (len)
        transmitP2(outBuff, len);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive explanation I really appreciate it.